# Pims "Unexpected Keyword Argument" and “invalid ImageJ metadata or corrupted file”

Tags: python, tiff, imagej, invalid-argument, trackpy

**The Context**:
I'm trying to use the package trackpy for research. I'm on a Mac and I'm using (mostly) Spyder. I’m following the trackpy walkthrough (https://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.2/tutorial/walkthrough.html) and I’m trying to use it on a tif file. Here’s my code:

```
#Install trackpy (https://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.2/installation.html)
!conda update conda --yes
!conda install -c conda-forge trackpy --yes

#Use trackpy (trackpy walkthrough: https://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.2/tutorial/walkthrough.html)
from __future__ import division, unicode_literals, print_function
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pims
import trackpy as tp

#Install libtif for pims.Tiffstack, per the README (which leads to this link: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/soft-matter/pims/blob/master/examples/loading%20video%20frames.ipynb)
!conda install libtiff --yes

frames = pims.TiffStack("/Users/(my username)/Documents/TSVIEW_Test_5_Grey_1.tif", as_grey=True)
```

**The Problems**: When I first wrote the code, I got the error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_grey'

According to the trackpy walkthrough, it should take as_grey as an argument.

However, when I restarted my computer, I got a different error message (without any code changes as far as I can tell):

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py:2113: UserWarning: invalid ImageJ metadata or corrupted file
>     warnings.warn('invalid ImageJ metadata or corrupted file')

Again, I didn't change the code between restarting it.

Interestingly, when I tried this code in a different python-running software, I got the first error again. I tried it in Google Colab. The only changes I made to the code were using pip instead of conda (Colab only supports pip), downloading the additional dependencies needed for pip per the trackpy install page (https://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.2/installation.html), and uploading the file to Colab per the 'External data: Drive, Sheets, and Cloud Storage' Colab guide.

**Things I've tried**:
I’ve researched both problems. For the first, I found a page that asked the same problem ([pims.Video parameter issue in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211247/pims-video-parameter-issue-in-spyder)), but the only solution provided is "an installation issue" where certain modules are "from the wrong source.” If this is right (is it?), what does it mean? How can I install the modules from the right source?

For the second, I found from the pims website that pims is based on the the tifffile dependency (http://soft-matter.github.io/pims/v0.4/tiff_stack.html). I then found the code that brought the error message (line 2415 from the tifffile.py page https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/external/tifffile/tifffile.py), but I still don’t know how to solve it.

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: `UserWarning: invalid ImageJ metadata or corrupted file` is a **warning**.